# AWS DMS CDC replication task not migrating the data and showing "Unchanged-toast-datum" instead of real value in LOB columns

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, dms

I am using AWS DMS in which I am migrating the data from Aurora Postgresql DB to Amazon S3. When I perform a full load operation I am getting whole data including LOB columns but in case of CDC Replication task I am getting the "Unchanged-Toast-Datum" in the LOB columns instead of the actual data. This is happening in case of "Update" records. In the S3 bucket I am getting empty column for that record, but other columns have updated data.

Error in Cloudwatch Logs: 2023-09-22T09:01:03:543435 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]D: Detected an 'unchanged-toast-datum' column value in column 'BillingDetails'. This column will be ignored from the data record. {operation:IDLE (51), tableName:ShipmentBilling, schemaName:public, columnName:BillingDetails} (postgres_test_decoding.c:1685)

How can I resolve this?